# Automatic keyboard xcode

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS development.  I need to make my keyboard appear when I enter the view without pressing anything; for example when I have a view with a `textField`, when I enter the view, I want the keyboard to appear automatically. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the textField to become the first responder. Try to call this method in the `viewDidAppear` method of the view controller that contains the textField.

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[yourTextField becomeFirstResponder]` method call in your class's `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLoad`.